# How do I match a list of strings to a list of of filenames so I can save those files into one master file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, string-matching

I have a list of barcodes.  I want to read and append files from a folder that match the barcode, but of course the barcodes are not a 1-to-1 match.

Example of the Barcode is `07002991H3` and an Example of the File Name is `07002991H3001`.

I am able to match the barcodes with a trimmed file name, but the file will is not able to read in

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

with open('BarcodeList.txt','r') as WaferList:

    lines = WaferList.read().splitlines()

    FileList = os.listdir('//FolderThatContainsFiles')

    df = []
    for file in FileList:
        for afile in lines:

            if afile == file.split("_")[0][0:10]:
                df = pd.read_csv(file)
  ### The "df" step above does not work ###

                print('success')
   ### The success part works  ####
```

I expect the df step above to read the csv of matched file, but instead I receive this message:

`FileNotFoundError: File b'07001382A7044_summary.csv' does not exist`

Comment: Where are you reading in your barcodes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give pandas the file path as well as the file name; try

```py
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('//FolderThatContainsFiles', file))
```